# Getting division by zero error with Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, lines, divide-by-zero

I am using this code to remove the lines from the following image:

[image: src]

I don't know the reason, but it gives me as output `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero error` on line 34 - `x0, x1, y0, y1 = (0, im_wb.shape[1], sum(y0_list)/len(y0_list), sum(y1_list)/len(y1_list))`.

What's the reason ? How can I fix it ?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('lines.png',0)

# Applies threshold and inverts the image colors
(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
im_wb = (255-im_bw)

# Line parameters
minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 10
color = 255
size = 1

# Substracts the black line
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(im_wb,1,np.pi/180,minLineLength,maxLineGap)[0]

# Makes a list of the y's located at position x0 and x1
y0_list = []
y1_list = []
for x0,y0,x1,y1 in lines:
    if x0 == 0:
        y0_list.append(y0)
    if x1 == im_wb.shape[1]:
        y1_list.append(y1)

# Calculates line thickness and its half
thick = max(len(y0_list), len(y1_list))
hthick = int(thick/2)

# Initial and ending point of the full line
x0, x1, y0, y1 = (0, im_wb.shape[1], sum(y0_list)/len(y0_list), sum(y1_list)/len(y1_list))

# Iterates all x's and prints makes a vertical line with the desired thickness
# when the point is surrounded by white pixels
for x in range(x1):
    y = int(x*(y1-y0)/x1) + y0
    if im_wb[y+hthick+1, x] == 0 and im_wb[y-hthick-1, x] == 0:
        cv2.line(img,(x,y-hthick),(x,y+hthick),colour,size)

cv2.imshow('clean', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The question reffers to this other one: [Python: How to OCR characters crossed by a horizontal line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149763/python-how-to-ocr-characters-crossed-by-a-horizontal-line)

Comment: What is the reason? How about y_0 list or y1_list being empty, for which len() would return 0.

Comment: Yes, but how they are empty ? I mean, the image is being loaded...

Comment: I don't think `HoughLine` is a good choice. I prefer morph-op, this is my result. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBpyo.png . You can also 
 have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667238/find-single-color-horizontal-spaces-in-image/47675213#47675213

Comment: Thanks. It's okay as always. But do you know why the variables are empty and gives me the error ?

Comment: @Silencer, also, the code you suggested work in find the horizontal line but if you take a look at the "source" of my answer, you will see that the solution will break the image by deletin all across. The result should be something [like this](https://imgur.com/a/LXeKz)

Answer (score 0):

Well the cause of the error is that the length is 0 of either `y0_list` or `y1_list` (or both). Since you initialize them in this for loop :

```
for x0,y0,x1,y1 in lines:
    if x0 == 0:
        y0_list.append(y0)
    if x1 == im_wb.shape[1]:
        y1_list.append(y1)
```

You can narrow your error down to either `lines` not having the expected values or your 2 `if` statements being faulty. I believe the problem is caused by the latter but the easiest check you can do is print out `lines` and check manually if your `if` statements would be triggered.

Comment: it's strange, still error... still 0 to y0 and y1 list

Comment: I updated my answer a bit. Could you show the contents of the `lines` variable? It seems that you expect to find the beginning of a line at `x=0`, which seems unlikely.

Comment: Well your `lines` list seems to contain just one line : (414, 23) - (416, 23). This isn't going to trigger your `if` conditions, resulting in empty lists, ultimately resulting in the exception. So I'm afraid you basically have some faulty reasoning going on, which is a completely different question.